# Prometheus email alert to show metric value

Tags: email, go, alert, metrics, prometheus

I have a label `cs_job_time` in Prometheus/Alert Manager and would like to send an email alert when a condition is met for another job. The email sends fine but is it possible to include the value of `cs_job_time` within the email? I can use `{{$value}}` for the metric in question but I would also like to print the value of `cs_job_time`.

I came across [this](https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/issues/549) but when I try

```
time = "{{  `cs_job_time{instance='%s', job='/'}` $labels.instance | query | first }}
```

or similar variants, I get the error message `"Error expanding alert template CSJobAlert with data '{map[] 2123}': runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference" source="alerting.go:199"`

Is it possible to email metric values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `printf` there from the example:

```
"{{ printf `cs_job_time{instance='%s', job='/'}` $labels.instance | query | first }}"
```

Be careful though, if there's no results then the `first` will fail. It's generally best to use a range statement as that'll be resilient to that.

Comment: thanks for the reply. That's fixed the issue but I'm now getting ` <first>: error calling first: first() called on vector with no elements"`. If I access `cs_job_time` from Prometheus, there is a value. I also tried changing `first` to `range` but got the error message in my original post but I'm sure I'm doing that wrong (sorry, I'm new to Go templating)

Comment: I'd guess your job label is incorrect. See https://prometheus.io/docs/visualization/template_examples/#simple-iteration for an example.

Comment: Thanks, it's working. I hardcoded the jobname and it worked. If anyone wants just the value, add the `value` parameter too. E.g. `{{ \`cs_job_time{instance='localhost:9091',job='jobname'}\` | query | first | value}}`